# Using PARAM values with Session State Server (SQL Server Model) for IIS App

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have an IIS application hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and are using the PARAM values to define the connection strings for our deployments. We are also using the membership role manager and the Session State Server within our application (sql server mode). This is creating a problem as we want the connection string to be completely dynamic and for that we are trying to write the string in C# on App_Start event. But the project throws an error "connectionstringname property not found" when we do that.

Basically our use case is:
We deploy same application across multiple elastic beanstalk instances and would like to depend on PARAM values to define which one is which. However the membership role manager and the session state server aren't allowing us to have the entire connection string in just those PARAM parameters.

Is there a way to achieve what we are trying to do?

Regards
Sunil Rai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can  be achieved by removing membership dependency from web project. We have to write our logic  instead of membership function and we can write one app setting  which will specify  server name "Demo" or "Live" and we can define our connection string in our C# code.I have implemented in my projects.